# Recommend a design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles

An application I'm working on processes Work Items. Depending on the state of a work item there are a number of actions available. "Complete" "Cancel" "Reassign" etc...

To provide the functionality for the actions I currently have an interface that looks something like this...

```
public interface IActionProvider{
    public void Complete(WorkItem workItem);
    public void Cancel (WorkItem workItem);
    public void Reassign(WorkItem workItem);
}
```

Then based on other details of the work item I have concrete implementations of the interface. Just for example...

```
public class NormalActionProvider :IActionProvider
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class UrgentActionProvider : IActionProvider
{
   ....
}
```

The problem is, if I want to add a new action, say... "Delegate" I have to update the interface which of course has effects on all of the implementations.

Does this violate the Open/Close Principle? Can you recommend a design pattern or refactor that may help me here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like command pattern would be suitable. You can modify/add more commands. The command classes are decoupled from the main program.

```
public interface IActionProvider{
    public void execute(WorkItem item,ActionType actionType);
}
```

ActionType represents Complete,Cancel & so on. You can keep adding more action types & plugin appropriate command classes.

Answer (score 3):

You could always add a Decorator to the IActionProvider interface (follow the [Decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really are trying to accomplish with your `IActionProvider`. If you really want to make it so that every implementation must be able to perform all of the actions that you consider to be important, then that should be a part of the interface that they implement. Interfaces work best if they are well-planned ahead of time so they don't have to change continually.

But it sounds like you don't necessarily want all actions to be implemented by all providers. I'd need to know more details to be able to give good advice, but one example would be to have the providers initialize themselves against a kind of event Bus. They could subscribe to those events that they care about, and perform actions only for the events that make sense for the specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

"Depending on the state of the workitem", brings the State Design Pattern

One way or another, you'll have to refactor you interface and eventually break client contracts.

If i have understood your problem correctly, then you have a WorkItemProcessor whose state changes depending 
on the WorkItem Sent to it.

Therefore your WorkItemProcessor becomes

```
// Context
    public class WorkItemProcessor
    {
        public IState CurrentState { get; set; }

        public WorkItemProcessor(IState initialState)
        {
            CurrentState = initialState;
        }

        public void Process(WorkItem workItem)
        {
            CurrentState.Handle(this, workItem);
        }
    }
```

Then we define multiple states that the WorkItemProcessor could potentially be in

```
// State Contract
    public interface IState
    {
        void Handle(WorkItemProcessor processor, WorkItem item);
    }

    // State One
    public class CompleteState : IState
    {
        public void Handle(WorkItemProcessor processor, WorkItem item)
        {
            processor.CurrentState = item.CompletenessConditionHoldsTrue ? (IState) this : new CancelState();
        }
    }

    // State Two
    public class CancelState : IState
    {
        public void Handle(WorkItemProcessor processor, WorkItem item)
        {
            processor.CurrentState = item.CancelConditionHoldsTrue ? (IState) this : new CompleteState();
        }
    }
```

Assuming your WorkItem Looks like

```
 // Request
    public class WorkItem
    {
         public bool CompletenessConditionHoldsTrue { get; set; }

         public bool CancelConditionHoldsTrue { get; set; }
    }
```

To put it all together

```
static void Main()
    {
      // Setup context in a state 
      WorkItemProcessor processor = new WorkItemProcessor(new CancelState());

      var workItem1 = new WorkItem {  CompletenessConditionHoldsTrue = true };
      var workItem2 = new WorkItem {  CancelConditionHoldsTrue = true };

      // Issue requests, which toggles state 
      processor.Process(workItem1);
      processor.Process(workItem2);

      Console.Read();
    }
```

Hope this gets you closer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I would also choose the command pattern. As an enhancement, you can combine it with the abstract factory method, so you can have a factory class for each command class, and all those factories implement a common factory interface.

For example:

```
// C#
public interface ICommand { void Execute(); }

public interface ICommandFactory { ICommand Create(); }

public class CommandFactoryManager
{
    private IDictionary<string, ICommandFactory> factories;

    public CommandFactoryManager()
    {
        factories = new Dictionary<string, ICommandFactory>();
    }

    public void RegisterCommandFactory(string name, ICommandFactory factory)
    {
        factories[name] = factory;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way, you can register new command factories dynamically. For example, you can load a DLL at runtime and fetch all the classes that implement the ICommandFactory interface using reflection, and you have a simple plugin system.